# Does Ubuntu install on Windows 8.1 with dual boot options

Tags: boot

I want to install Ubuntu on an HP Laptop with Windows 8.1 installed. Does the Ubuntu installer allow the dual boot setup?

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste That *refers* to WUBI, but the answer itself doesn't require it. Read the answer ;)

Comment: This should help if you have Windows 8.1 installed UEFI. (Read the first answer at the top and don't read the question at all!) http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. Just stick to the latest version of Ubuntu - 14.04 LTS, and allow installer to shrink existing Windows partitions automatically. See [Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, I have Windows 8.1 dual booted with Ubuntu 14.04. There are detailed instructions in this forum on how to do it. In essence, here is what I did.

Disable secure boot in the BIOS.
Disabled hibernation and fast boot in Windows 8.1.
Use a partition tool to shrink my windows partition.
Install Ubuntu (creating partitions in the free space)
Run 'boot-repair' cd.

It's dual booting fine.

Comment: What do you mean this forum? This is a Question/Answer site. The forums are ubuntuforums.org. Also, a link would be very helpful, because I am going to try a dual-boot soon and a guide would be very helpful.

Comment: Forum / Questions and answers site. Come on, you know what I mean !! Search for windows dual boot in this 'Questions/Answers' site, they are all listed and easy to view. Here is the link, http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html